# Finding latitude and longitude limits for a sub-region given its name

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, region, copernicus

In order to extract climate data from [Copernicus](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/home), there's the Sub-region extraction section that allows one to extract data from a region within specific coordinate limits.

I am wondering how should one do to find the latitude and longitude limits for a specific sub-region, given the name of that region.

Taking the Iberian Peninsula as an example, what should one do in order to find its North, South, East and West limits?

Comment: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/toolbox/doc/how-to/1_how_to_retrieve_data/1_how_to_retrieve_data.html#retrieve-a-geographical-subset-and-change-the-default-resolution

Comment: https://climate.copernicus.eu/media/59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a better method, I have used [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/).

Then, in order to find out the limits for that specific region, in this case, the Iberian Peninsula, I have selected specific regions in the map by clicking once on top of a specific place and a pop-up with coordinates appear, as one can see in the image bellow.

In the process one will need to go through a variety of decisions, when defining those limits. In my case, I haven't considered islands.

[image: Iberian Peninsula coordinates in the East]